# Flutter - Persist login state flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my `main.dart` as follows:

```
child: MaterialApp(
  title: Constants.appTitle,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    fontFamily: Constants.fontSansFrancisco,
  ),
  home: AuthScreen(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  onGenerateRoute: _appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
),
```

How can I change my home to `DashboardScreen()` instead of `AuthScreen()` using a `async` function returning a `future` value:

```
  Future<String?> getSession() => storage.read(key: "token");
```

I want to change home to `DashboardScreen()` if getSession() returns a non-empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a splash screen that in splash's initState function or controller class get token and then Decision what page you want to open.

Or do this in AuthScreen class.